# rails callback, perform and store a calculation in active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

a job has many job delivery costs, a job delivery cost belongs to a job. I am trying to write a method in the job model which calculates the total price of a job delivery cost and stores it in its column total_job_delivery_cost.

I am currently using this method in the job delivery cost controller to display the total in the view. But I need to actually store the value.

```
  def calculate_delivery_total(array)
    array.inject(0) { |total, item| (total + item.cost_per_unit * item.hour_count) * item.quantity }
  end
```

So my question in more broader terms is, how do use a callback to perform an action in a different model. I need to make sure it works out only with the associated record, not all the job delivery costs. I am unsure how to do this in the model.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly then this may do what you want:

```
class DeliveryCost < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :job

  after_commit do
    job.update_total_cost if job
  end

  def total_cost
    # calculate total cost for DeliveryCost instance here
    # something like:
    cost_per_unit * hour_count * quantity
  end
end

class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :delivery_costs

  def update_total_cost
    total_job_delivery_cost = calculate_total_cost
  end

  private
  def calculate_total_cost
    delivery_costs.inject(0) { |total, delivery_cost| total + delivery_cost.total_cost }
  end
end
```

Here `after_commit` is triggered when any changes to DeliveryCost table be made.

Please ask if something is not clear.